# how to display blob in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, blob

```
<?php
    try{
        include("dbconnectie.php");
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id_img = '2'");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "<table>";
            foreach($result as &$data) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["brand"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["model"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["cond"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $data["price"] . "</td>";
                    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($blob).'"/>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

So I managed to save files as longblob in phpmyadmin database, but the problem is that i don't know how to display it. Please help

Comment: Consider *not* storing blobs in the database. Upload the files to a location on the server, then store the *filename*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$blob` try to call the image field name from the database.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $data["image"] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: it just displays the broken image icon

Comment: I am not sure what field name you have in your database. Make sure you are calling the correct field. Moreover, Image should be present in your database.

Comment: The field name is image and the image is present but it shows up as a broken image icon.

Comment: `echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $result["image"] ).'"/>';`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, `$blob` is not defined. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($data['blob']) . '">';
```